# Getting app not installed error while installing flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

Facing an app not installed issue on only one of the Samsung devices. Couldn't check any ADB logs as the end-user is facing this issue.

Comment: try to uninstall via adb command adb uninstall "your pkg name"

Answer (score 1):

You need add multiDexEnabled true in android/app/build.gradle file.

```
android {
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            ...
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        ...
    }
    
    dependencies {
      implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    }
```